# Increase training MSE in a special case of multiple linear regression

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I am doing a special case of multiple linear regression with variables x1, x2, and y. For a fixed degree i, the predictor variables are 
x1,x1^2,x1^3...x1^i,  x2,x2^2,x2^3...x2^i,  x1*(x2^(i-1)),(x1^2)*(x2^(i-2))...(x1^(i-1))*(x2)
and I am predicting y.
I used 10 fold cross validation method to look for the best i from 1 to 10.
The result is 3 but both training and testing MSE increase after i=3. I am wondering why even training MSE increases? If I add more predictors shouldn't it decreases? The x1s and x2s are between 0 and 100 and y is between 90 and 200.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?